# Iterating over irregular data with Ruby while 'filling in the blanks'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I'm rolling the following:

- Rails 3.2.9
- Highcharts
- State Machine

I've got an irregular set of data that represents the change of state of hundreds of linux boxes. Each box checks into a central ping server every two minutes.

Every time a device heartbeats, the ping server checks if the device's current state is offline and if so, changes the state to online and sets the heartbeat table's online col to true and inserts the time this happened.

On the ping server, we have a cron that runs a rake task every 5 minutes. This finds all devices with a heartbeat less than the time now minus 5 minutes.

If it discovers a device is offline, it sets the device state to offline and marks to heartbeat table with the time of the last heartbeat and a 0.

We've been doing this for a while and it seems like an efficient way to store the uptime data without creating a row for 500 devices every 5 minutes.

The table looks a little like this:

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+
| created_at          | dev_id | online |
+---------------------+--------+--------+
| 2012-10-08 16:29:16 |   2345 |      0 |
| 2012-11-21 16:40:22 |   2345 |      1 |
| 2012-11-03 19:15:00 |   2345 |      0 |
| 2012-11-08 09:15:01 |   2345 |      1 |
| 2012-11-08 09:18:03 |   2345 |      0 |
| 2012-11-09 17:57:22 |   2345 |      1 |
| 2012-12-09 13:57:23 |   2345 |      0 |
| 2012-12-09 14:57:25 |   2345 |      1 |
| 2012-12-09 15:00:30 |   2345 |      0 |
| 2012-12-09 15:57:31 |   2345 |      1 |
| 2012-12-09 16:07:35 |   2345 |      0 |
| 2012-12-09 16:37:38 |   2345 |      1 |
| 2012-12-09 17:57:40 |   2345 |      0 |
+---------------------+--------+--------+
```

Following Ryan Bate's fantastic [Railscast on Highcharts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts), I can create a line graph of this data with irregular intervals.

**The chart and data series**

Following this example:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

And using a data series something like this:

```
 = @devices.heartbeats.map { |o|  o.online == true ? 1 : 0 }
```

It was plotting the line graph pretty nicely.

**Where I'm stuck**

The graph finishes at the last time it checked in and I need the graph to show a point at Now. In Ryan's example, he maps a zero to a date if there's no value. I can't translate this part.

I'm trying to achieve a graph like the stack bar chart but can't get the data sorted.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

How can I format my query so I get the data until Now as well as each individual point so I can create such a graph?